# Are ACH transfers between individuals possible?

Tags: banking, online-banking, electronic-payment, ach

All the information I've found on ACH transfers for individuals apply to the scenario in which the individual makes payments to an institution of some kind (usually a business).

But are ACH transfers between *indviduals* possible?  (Or, more precisely, are ACH transfer possible between **two bank accounts**, both of which are owned by individuals?)

Comment: In what kind of institution is the source money located? brokerage? bank? under your mattress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, many banks offer such a service. Often such payments can be made through their "bill pay" interface. You log in to your account on the bank's website, enter the recipient's routing and account numbers, and off you go.

You could ask your bank whether they offer this. If not, you could change banks to one that does.

Comment: The last (and only) time someone sent me an "online bill pay", their bank mailed me a check.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: A mailed check is a separate option (though at some banks it is the only option).  With my bank, I can specify a payee either with an account/routing number (in which case they get an ACH deposit) or a street address (in which case they get a check in the mail).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any tips on which banks you know specifically offer this rather than trying to check/contact a bunch of banks manually.

Comment: Will update comment as I find more info, but so far looks like BofA supports this although I didn't complete the process, but I didn't find it with Chase bank.

Comment: LendingClub as a bank also seems to support this option, and their process is very straightforward/clear in presenting it, although I've not gone through to complete the process. BofA was a bit more complicated to navigate for the option.

Comment: @David: My FNBO checking account does it - same account I was describing back then.